# MYSQL - Trigger on a specified column

Tags: mysql, triggers

I have a table called 'Student' which have some columns (id, classID, email, etc..), and a table 'Question' which have columns (id, studentID, teacherID). A student can have many Questions.
The problem is, that, I'm  trying to delete all questions related to the student which 'classID' column is modified. I've looking in many topic related to this kind of question, but seems that nothing works for me.
Student Table:

```
Field   Type    Null    Key Default Extra
ID      int PRI NO      auto_increment
classID int YES MUL
```

Question Table:

```
Field      Type Null    Key Default Extra
ID      int PRI NO    auto_increment
studentID   int YES MUL     
teacherID   int YES MUL
```

My trigger:

```
DELIMITER ;;
CREATE TRIGGER deleteStudentQuestionOnUpdate AFTER UPDATE ON student FOR EACH ROW
IF NOT (old.classID = new.classID) THEN DELETE FROM question WHERE studentID = id;
END IF;;

DELIMITER ;
```

Thank you =)

Comment: IF old.classID <> new.classID is easier than IF NOT (old.classID = new.classID) and WHERE studentID = id; should be WHERE studentID = new.id

Comment: Hello. Thank you. I've tried to modify it again, but it still doesn't work. Error is: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'DELIMITER' at line 1
My trigger:  ```DELIMITER;;
CREATE TRIGGER deleteStudentQuestionOnUpdate AFTER UPDATE ON student FOR EACH ROW
IF(old.classID <> new.classID) THEN DELETE FROM question WHERE studentID = id;
END IF;;
DELIMITER ;
```

Comment: Have you tried without setting delimiters and what ide are you using?

Comment: Add space after first delimiter and end if see https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/4s8edCjtW1A7vYc4nk29Da/0

Comment: I'm using POPSQL - I've done what you said, I've eliminated the delimiters, now it works. But, I'm not getting the result I'm expecting. I expect that, every time from the table Student when 'ClassId' column is modified, and, if it is a different value, the related row on Question Table, which has the related "studentID" (it is a foreign key of Student Table), to be deleted. But, the trigger don't do that, I guess it is because on where clause, possible, is an ambiguity between studentID and ID, because, the Question table have both of them.

Comment: How can I modify the where clause, so, the 'studentID' to be the column from Question Table, and 'ID' to be the column from student table? Thank you so much for helping me =)

Comment: Should be NEW.id (see first comment)

Comment: See amended link